# choose function for large values

Tags: r, statistics, formula

As part of a formula I am computing, I need to compute large b inomial coefficients

This is something like :

```
choose(1598,999)
```

but the result from R is just inf. Is there some way to get around that? Or some way to approximate the result in any way? It is just that I am trying to work with a formula which has sample size as n (1598) and another parameter 
as p (in this casw 999).

So I want to compute

```
with n->16000
b->1000
c()->w
c()->w1
    for (k in 2:(n-1)){
      k*(k-1)*chooseZ((n-k),(b-1))->w
    c(w1,w)->w1
    }
```

While there is no error the result is wrong:

```
sum(w1)
Error in sum(w1) : invalid 'type' (raw) of argument
    > head(w1)
    [1] 01 00 00 00 01 00
```

Comment: That would be a 458 digit number. There are some arbitrary precision packages if you do some Googling....

Comment: @joran do you mean like rmpfr? how would i use that in  this casse? it is really just because the formula is that way

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used that package. But you aren't going to be able to calculate with numbers that big in any reasonable way in any language without some sort of arbitrary precision capability.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and work with the log of whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: but I would need to cpmpute the very large coefficient....there is no way to get aroudn that

Answer (score 4):

Try using `chooseZ` from the `gmp` package.

```
library(gmp)
chooseZ(1598,999)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 24278696426445719206411636658492530369104863587241559663553520984424347733955902209013400793410551248995223418598838685432844582570031038690080807851906250009888240115104285225539059084804496423089545062262737596184912679476923113553162874564650288993564978319447910715500162623621305510917593005744632186322124862050089421200736125546497281717999352152426164243210315176391085915104025111403152439452509792706140328536251214887318149223708091336739500080000
```

Note that the result is a bigz class object and larger than the numeric class can represent.

Comment: does that mean you can still just normally calculate with it like ,umtiply and divid?

Comment: To some extent. It will represent results as bigz (integer) or bigq (rationals) accordingly. As long as the final result of your calculation is within the domain of a numeric you can convert to that afterwards.

Comment: when you devide you get a ratio which you cant divide again - if lu is a big integer ad i is a ratio then i/lu is non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("/.bigz", "/.bigq") for "/"    is there some way aroun?

Comment: I updated the question - it does not work for the formula

Comment: Convert lu to bigq: `i/as.bigq(lu)`

Comment: okay...could oyu have a look at the edited question - in the case outlined the return is just very messed..do you have an idea how to recode that

Comment: the question is now correct..there was an unintended typo in the thing before

Comment: `chooseZ` is vectorised. Therefore you don't need the loop: `k <- 2:(n-1); sum(k*(k-1)*chooseZ((n-k),b-1))` gives an answer of approximately 2.22e1625, which is an unphysically large number.

Comment: the problem is that i HAVE  another multiplication

 k <- 2:(n-1); sum(k*(k-1)*chooseZ((n-k),b-1)((mat[k,1])^2-(mat[k+1 ,1])^2))
where mat is a matrix fromw hcih a value is pulled - then get Error: attempt to apply non-function

Comment: This is becoming a different problem. It might help to ask as another question, but I can't see why it would be an issue.

Comment: please see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921700/multiplication-of-very-large-with-small-values

Comment: the problem is that i a want to multiply that big integer with a very small number which if i convert to big integer is 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `print` function with the digits specified. Don't know if it'll work for this though.

The syntax would be

```
print(choose(1598,999),digits = 20)
```

I think print caps it at 22 digits. Check if this works

Comment: The largest integer that can be displayed in R is 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647 Your answer is 2.427869642 E+457 which I calculated using [this](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php)