# multiplication of very large with small values

Tags: r, floating-point, multiplication

as the result of a large binomial coefficient I summed sorry stored a number as big integer (from the gmp) package

```
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] > chooseZ(1599,999)
```

Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 64702725976477841685087011694882593433664461459998756503370133423490886710992479387020713114439119078572270410565905096678530812549132718109065352925330156276352159906752920126061592461003982967533637590930195693832792290806000097619179060714793020167850667221328682056807933391950779186595385360309444776548462757363488307499961774581415255778468273486215727708155489945082243963752226921889401251140938597561863975549109487674702867681182063412410767713200

now I would need to multiply it with

```
[1] 1.884357e-08
```

if I convert into big integer I get that the number 1.88 e-8 is just rounded to 0 which means the multiplication is 0. How can I multiply both numbers in R

Comment: Your binomial coefficient is well within the range of the IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point format used by R.  What goes wrong if you simply convert your big integer to a float and then multiply that float with your smaller number?

Comment: i do also have numbers which are not...that is the main problem..as in th eupdate...

Comment: nobody able to suggest someh?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you divide your big number by 1x10^8 (as integer) and then multiply by 18884357?

Comment: i need to do these operation again and again is there somethign like a functionw hich would do your prop on all numbrs like that?

Comment: also that answer is wrong because if divided by 1e8 and multiplied by the number is not the same as multiplied by the number origianlly used

Comment: try use the bigz functionS: a <- mul.bigz(big, 1884357)
div.bigz(a, 10000000)

Answer (score 1):

Try use big rational instead:

```
huge <- as.bigq(yourcoef,d=1)
tiny <- as.bigq(yoursmall,d=1)
mul.bigq(huge,tiny)
```

Comment: it tells me that there is the function bigq.mu not ...otherwise that could work but cant find the function in the official documentation

Comment: sorry, I typed it wrong.